# Is there a way to represent N in terms of X?

Tags: statistics

Using X<sub>i</sub> # of observations How do I mathematically represent N (the sample size) in terms of X? The summation (Σ) sign just tells me to add each of the individual values in X<sub>i</sub>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, $$N=\sum_{X_i \in \text{ sample}}1 $$
or $$N=\#\text{(sample)}$$ where $\#$ stands for cardinality. The latter approach is trickier because when some sample values happen to be the same, because one has to think of the sample as a *multiset* rather than a set.

Yet another version: 
$$N=\sum_{i}  {F}(X_i)$$
where $F:  \mathbb R\to \{1\}$ is a constant function.

Comment: Is there a way to translate that into Excel or R?